# How to read both from user input and txt file - C Console

Tags: c, file, input, console, scanf

I have a program where a user enters a list of real number pairs, separated by a comma, and the program would then calculate it's mean, median, mode, count the number of data etc...

So far it reads user input fine. I am just wondering is there a way for the program to read from a .txt file as well. So a txt file filled with real number pairs separated by commas.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot 
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element 
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Separately sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int n1, n2;
    int x[10] = { 0 };
    int y[10] = { 0 };

    int capacity = 0;

    size_t n = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    int ch = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {

        scanf_s(" %d , %d ", &n1, &n2);
            x[i] = n1;
            y[i] = n2;

    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d , %d\n", x[j], y[j]);

    }
    quickSort(x, 0, n-1);
    printArray(x, n);

    printf("Minimum is: %d", x[0]);
    printf("Maximum is: %d", x[n-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to read the txt file from my program using CMD, it gives me a bunch of numbers.

```
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
```

I suppose I have to use FILE* stream or something along that line, however I am not sure how to implement it using fscan_s...

Comment: You can redrect input from the file: `./program_name < filename`

Comment: Hmmm that seem to work! But why does that work, however when my proof just use something like: "program_name filename.txt" and it would work?

Comment: Because `<` automatically changes the program's standard input to read from the file. Doing it without `<` requires you to write code in the program to use `fopen()` to open the file and read from that instead of standard input.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `scanf_s` and `fscanf_s` is simply where they draw input from, as you have rightfully said. the first identifier passed to `fscanf_s` is a `FILE *` - a pointer to a file stream. This file stream is initialised, and the pointer obtained, through a call to `fopen` or a variant via the returned value. Once you have this pointer, you just need to pass it into `fscanf_s`. It should look something like this:

```
FILE *text_file = fopen("C:\Path\To\File.txt", "r"); //"r" == open for reading
if (text_file == NULL) //error in fopen() e.g. you don't have read permission or the file doesn't exist
{
    puts("error");
    return 1;
}
fscanf_s(text_file, format_string, varargs);
```

Side note based on your comment. It would be feasible to draw input from a file specified in the command line just by replacing the path to the file in `fopen()` with the `argv` argument

To your comment:
Sorry about the slow response. The docs say this about `fopen_s()`, the "more secure" version of `fopen()`.

```
errno_t fopen_s(
   FILE** pFile,
   const char *filename,
   const char *mode
);
```

Basically, the syntax is a bit different. Rather than setting a `FILE` pointer to be the return value, you pass in a pointer to that pointer as the first parameter. Usage looks like:

```
FILE *file_ptr;
errno_t check_this = fopen_s(&file_ptr, filename, mode);
```

If you need more information on how passing the pointer-to-pointer works, just ask.

Comment: It gave me an erro and asks me to use fopen_s and that requires an extra parameter. Any idea what parameter do i have to give it?
`FILE* text_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");`
...
`while(fscanf_s(text_file," %d , %d ", &n1, &n2) == 2)`